# fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository cuando hago git push origin master

Tags: git, github

Estoy subiendo un proyecto a github y cuando le doy `git push origin master`, me sale esto:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué te sale si haces `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver este problema, probablemente te haga falta el remote, por favor verifica si tienes un remote llamado `origin` con el siguiente comando:

```
git remote -v
```

Si no existe el remote `origin`, entonces agregalo de la siguiente manera:

```
git remote add origin url/al/fork/de/github.git
```

Y posteriormente para asegurarte de que el remote que pusiste sea el upstream, puedes hacer el `push` de la siguiente forma:

```
git push -u origin master
```

O:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Con eso debes tener todo configurado.

<sup>Esta respuesta es una traducción de [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637954/5622844).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Mil gracias por tu ayuda me funciono,me queda la pregunta por qué sucede esto, ya que en los anteriores archivos en los que he trabajado no había sucedido?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/337006)